# Flex4 Image cache in Spark:List - Using itemDestructionPolicy="never"

Tags: apache-flex, image, caching

I have a List with Images. I'm not that concerned about the flickering as I'm about the redownloading that happens with urls like http://www.example.com/?img=boat&color=453721, that I generate and cache in the php side. No problem with urls like http://www.example.com/img/boat.jpg. I'm partially considering using server redirection (sending headers), hoping it works.

But before -as the lists are not very big- I would like to consider trying to use this approach: http://flexponential.com/2010/01/10/caching-images-loaded-from-a-spark-item-renderer/. That's using the itemDestructionPolicy="never" with a List. The example is a DropDownList, but I wonder how to apply it to a List Skin.

I have tried disabling the virtual layout, but that's not convincing... I would like the creation of items to be 'on demand'... and forbid the destruction till the deletion/change of the list, the dataProvider, or the itemRenderer. Or at least any other solution that doesn't imply reloading the image from the server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that I got wasn't directly produced by the flex client. It was just that my server PHP script didn't send the proper headers.

As soon as it started sending properly the 'Last-Modified' and 'Etag' header, the Flex client started acting as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else helps, you can roll your own image cache based on Dictionary (url is the key, image is value). Items should ask for images some ImageLoader class (your own), which will check cache and if url is not there, download it. Images are passed to items asyncronously via callback function. When receiving result, item should check if it already removed from list.